# NetworkUtil for internet check in KMM

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

how to check the internet availability in KMM (actual/expect)

ANDROID

```
actual class NetworkUtils actual constructor() {
    actual fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
        val connectivityManager =
            application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val networkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected
    }
}
```

COMMON

```
expect class NetworkUtils() {
    fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean
}
```

IOS

```
actual class NetworkUtils {
    actual fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
      //todo ?
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

in IOS

```
actual fun isNetworkAvailable(): Boolean {
        return runBlocking { isConnected() }
    }

    private suspend fun isConnected(): Boolean {
        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            val url = NSURL(string = "https://www.google.com")
            val request = NSURLRequest.requestWithURL(url)

            val task = NSURLSession.sharedSession.dataTaskWithRequest(
                request = request,
                completionHandler = { _, _, error ->
                    val connected = error == null
                    continuation.resume(connected)
                }
            )

            task.resume()
        }
    }
```